# Cannot Print Void Method from Main

Tags: java, printing, void, anagram

I made a main method, insertion sort and want it to print out properly in my tester class.  I know that it cannot print because its a void method using arrays and I need it to be a  string to print, I'm just not sure what to edit in my method or my print line to make it feasible.

METHOD

```
public static void insertionSort(String[] inputList) 
        {
            OrderStrings c = new OrderStrings();

            for (int i = 1; i < inputList.length; i++)
                {
                    String index = inputList[i];
                    int j = i;
                    while ( j > 0 && c.compare((sort(inputList[j])), sort(inputList[j-1])) > 0)
                        {
                            inputList[j] = inputList[j-1];
                            j--;
                        }
                    inputList[j] = index;


                }
        }
```

TESTER

```
@Test
    public void testInsertionSort()
        {
            AnagramUtil insertionTest = new AnagramUtil();


            String[] test2 = { "ComputerScience" };

            System.out.print("Testing Insertion Sort");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(insertionTest.insertionSort("sorted" + test2);
//the above is the line that will not print
//it says "- The method insertionSort(String[]) in the type AnagramUtil is not applicable for the arguments(String)"
        }
```

Comment: A `void` method doesn't return anything. What would you expect that to print?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'd like the tester to show that my method insertion sort has worked.  how would I test and see if it works if I cannot get it to print?

Comment: You can change the array [in place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) or by returning a new, sorted array. The second method gives you more options and is less [error prone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). Without `AnagramUtil` and `OrderStrings`, this isn't a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it's hard to answer your question beyond this.